# Perl regexp: how to start matching text in part of file after I have find a "flag" string in the context?

Tags: regex, perl

Apologize for the way I describe my question, maybe it will be much clarified if I give the instance as below:
Consider the case that I have a certain file, and it is separated into different section with each beginning with a certain string consider as flag: e.g.
consider "From Clock" as the flag I mentioned about
example_file:

```
From Clock:  fdbk_bufg_cell_in_net
  To Clock:  fdbk_bufg_cell_in_net

Setup :           NA  Failing Endpoints,  Worst Slack           NA  ,  Total Violation           NA
Hold  :           NA  Failing Endpoints,  Worst Slack           NA  ,  Total Violation           NA
PW    :            0  Failing Endpoints,  Worst Slack        5.501ns,  Total Violation        0.000ns
```

Pulse Width Checks

```
Clock Name:         fdbk_bufg_cell_in_net
Waveform(ns):       { 0.000 3.500 }
Period(ns):         7.000
Sources:            { my_atspeed_mmcm/CLKFBOUT }

Check Type  Corner  Lib Pin   Reference Pin  Required(ns)  Actual(ns)  Slack(ns)  Location      Pin
Min Period  n/a     BUFGCE/I  n/a            1.499         7.000       5.501      BUFGCE_X0Y35  fdbk_bufg_cell/I
```

---

```
From Clock:  mmcm_clkout
  To Clock:  mmcm_clkout

Setup :           NA  Failing Endpoints,  Worst Slack           NA  ,  Total Violation           NA
Hold  :            0  Failing Endpoints,  Worst Slack        0.123ns,  Total Violation        0.000ns
PW    :          625  Failing Endpoints,  Worst Slack       -0.195ns,  Total Violation     -121.875ns
```

Now I only want to match the "PW :" line in "From Clock: mmcm_clkout" part, how do I do so?

Comment: Sorry, the "contex" and the flag should be in different line

Comment: Please edit your post with the actual format. Are they on consecutive lines, or do you need to match anywhere between flag_2 and another flag? Are flags recognisable?

Comment: Hi jcaron, I have put a example as above, please check. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something along these lines:

```
my $match = 0;
while (<>)
{
    if (/^From Clock: (\w+)/)
    {
        $match = ($1 eq "mmcm_clkout");
    } elsif ($match && /^PW: whatever/)
    {
        # do whatever you want with the line
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi jcaron, I'm thinking the same using a match flag. But there's a lot sequence to follow in the remaining text which is in the exact format I wanted to match with. Let me try out. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it works. Consider you reset the flag to 0 after the first match. Thx

Comment: If every "section" starts with "From Clock: " and there's only one line starting with PW: in each section, then that's already the case: `$match` will be true in each section for mmcm_clkout, and false for all others. If you indeed have more PW: in a section (and only want to match the first one), or sections starting with something else, then indeed you need to reset `$match`.